# MPI4PY - Can I predict padding size?

Tags: python, mpi, pickle, mpi4py

Consider the following program, which provides one byte for padding, which is insufficient.

```
import pickle
from mpi4py import MPI


s = ''
f = pickle.dumps(s)
print(len(f))
w = MPI.COMM_WORLD.irecv(len(f)+1)
MPI.COMM_WORLD.send(f, dest=0)
f = w.wait()
print(len(f))
```

It yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 10, in <module>
    f = w.wait()
  File "mpi4py/MPI\Request.pyx", line 235, in mpi4py.MPI.Request.wait
  File "mpi4py/MPI\msgpickle.pxi", line 411, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_wait
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Message truncated, error stack:
MPI_Wait(request=0x000001C6A3EC78D8, status0x00000073023EF3A0) failed
Message truncated; 11 bytes received but buffer size is 11
```

How can I know how much extra to add to the message, such that the transmission is guaranteed to succeed?

Answer (score -1):

If you call the lowercase function with no arguments you will get a default buffer of size 32k.

```
w = MPI.COMM_WORLD.irecv()
```

If you want to specify the size of the buffer you need to pass in a buffer object as argument with the correct size. In your code you are only specifying an integer as the buffer.

Also in this case, since you are using the lowercase versions the mpi4py package will pickle your data which will make it longer. You would have to write something like follows:

```
recvbuf = bytearray(b' ' * len(pickle.dumps(f)))
w = MPI.COMM_WORLD.irecv(buf=recvbuf)
```

If you want to specify the length of your data however I would recommend looking into the uppercase implementations of the functions and using numpy arrays. It is shown in the docs [here](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#point-to-point-communication).

Comment: That one has a limit - 32k by default.